# Handling client-side authorization with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm building a client that uses Firebase, the Firebase JavaScript SDK, the Firebase Authentication service, and the Real Time Database for persistence.

Following a number of different sources, I have the authentication piece working well, but I'm finding limited options for authorization for what I'd consider an efficient solution.

What I *want* to do is attach a single key/value of `role: 'admin'` to the user's auth record so that I can conduct both authentication and authorization with only one client-based call to the Firebase backend.

- I've read about attaching custom claims to the Firebase Authentication record, but I've only seen folks using the Firebase Admin library (backend) to both set the token and parse the token. I'm trying to not add additional calls through Firebase functions or a custom Express server, if I can help it.
- Adding a separate User profile record to the RTDB is easy, and I can store the auth data there. However, this will always require a simultaneous call for Authentication and Authorization, which, again, seems very inefficient and excludes secure offline use of the client (if roles change on the RTDB).
- It also seems inefficient to make a client-based call for authentication, then fire a mandatory second client-based call to retrieve authorization data from a Firebase function (or any other backend service) that can implement the Firebase admin library.

Main question: Is there a way with JavaScript to achieve the goal of setting/retrieving both authentication and authorization data from the Firebase Authentication service with a single request to the backend and processing on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two options you've given are the idiomatic approaches for custom roles.

- If you embed the role into the user's token as a custom claim, you'll get it in the authentication request. Since this is an operation that elevates permissions, it should be done in a trusted environment, such as a server you control, Cloud Functions, or (if infrequent enough) from your development machine.
- If you don't want to do that, and want to store it in the database, you'll need an extra request. The overhead of that call is usually not a performance problem.

A combination of the two is also possible: identify the initial "system administrator" UID manually, and then use that in your database security rules to allow the to grant additional rights to other users. But that will also have the roles in the database.

Instead of finding reasons to not use these idiomatic approaches, I recommend implementing one and seeing if your concerns surface in practice.

Comment: `If you embed the role into the user's token as a custom claim, you'll get it in the authentication request` -- But how do you access a custom claim on the client side? I'm not seeing this achieved in any documentation?

Comment: `The overhead of that call is usually not a performance problem` -- I am not as concerned about performance as much as I'm concerned about Firebase RTDB usage costs (reads) over time and using the client offline.

Comment: If you're already using the realtime database, reading `role: 'admin'` from is a tiny cost. This sounds like premature optimization to me. The custom claims should be available on the client, which was a recent change. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Let me provide a little more context, because you are assuming I am building a new app from scratch, which is not the case. I am attempting to migrate an existing app with usage and the question is being asked with legitimate cost concerns.

Comment: The size of`"role": "admin"` in JSON is 15 characters. Reading that from the database at a cost at [$1/GB](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) comes down to $0.000000015 per user, or >66M users per $1. If that is not within reason for your use-case, you can store the data as a custom claim in the token, where there is no charge for bandwidth.